# embedded testing to protocol stack development

Tags: testing, embedded, network-protocols

I am now working in embedded testing domain(avionics) and i would like to shift over my carreer to something like developement which is mainly like Protocol stack development. So what i need to know is some kind of real time projects (Networking or protocol development) which i could put into my resume so that the recruiter can at least shortlist me.
I have an apt knowledge in C and a bit of Linux OS knowledge to.

Can anyone suggest me some best place or site where i could do some real time projects where
I could do some kind of development from my side as an offline activity at home and get going on.
Are there any simulation type environments supported?

Comment: Why are you interested in protocol stack development in particular?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get your hands on functional specs/protocol specs and architecture documents. For open-source or industry standard protocols, you can find most specs on the web (eg: 3GPP, PacketCable, IETF, etc..). If not, the developer(s) should not mind sharing the docs with you.
2. Search on [Github](http://www.github.com) for projects related to the protocols you are working on. Download the code and read it. When you are able to understand how it works, add a patch, fix a bug or code your new feature. Most importantly, get your hands dirty.
3. If you are looking to get into networking (TCP/IP etc.) domain, NS-2(or 3) is a good place to start. But it is largely used only for simulations/academic stuff, not much in industry. For lower layers (L2,L1), most industry-grade stack development is proprietary. In which case, the best way to get in is to suggest improvements/fix bugs in the code you are testing. If you can spot the bugs in the code that the developer cannot, that will weigh in on your favor to get into dev.
4. Play around with code as much as possible (on GitHub or otherwise). Build a tool that automates/streamlines the testing process. This will demonstrate your coding skills. That coupled with your protocol knowledge gained through steps 1-3 above should put you in a great position for landing that next dev assignment.

Answer (score 0):

[NS-2](http://nsnam.isi.edu/nsnam/index.php/Main_Page) is the most widely used development environment for new networking protocols. It doesn't simulate a real bare-metal real-time system, but provides an extensive framework for developing new protocols and gauging their characteristics under varying network conditions.

Comment: @theatrus,Thanks a lot.If this stack which i wwould develop,i want to run it on a RTOS,atleast a simulator.Is there anyway by which i can do it.Let say for example,i wann develop the IPV6 UDP stack and i check the validity of this stack by downloading this one to something like a board which has an RTOS and sends message to another machine which has the actual stack and validate the message which i send.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap) site is a good place for open source development projects,
There is a [Embedded Systems software](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=749) page which might have things of interest.
Besides that, the Networking and Emulator projects might also be worth looking at.

[NS-2](http://nsnam.isi.edu/nsnam/index.php/Main_Page) and the newer [NS-3](http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) are quite popular in the academic protocol development and modeling space.
You could even enter into their development itself (**NS-3** is quite new).
NS-2 core is `C++` and has a Objected-Oriented Tcl environment for simulation.
NS-3 is fresh with a Python interface.

Comment: Thanks nik,But i am a bit confused over like whetehr is it the right time to switch over development or jst jump pver to protocol testing.I am doing avionics testing as of now.